# Python : create a new column using numpy using pandas aggregation with time difference in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datraframe as follows:

```
 id            timestamp                     amount   
100aard    2021-03-13 01:21:36.007000         4000
100aard    2021-03-13 01:23:36.007000         3000
100aard    2021-03-13 01:33:36.007000         1000
100aard    2021-03-13 01:21:36.007000        10300
```

Now I want to implement two rules on this df.

1. If any two consecutive transactions happens between 150 seconds then **both** the transactions should not be allowed.
2. If any transaction amount is more than say 5000, then that transaction should not be allowed.

So the resultant df should look like:

```
  id            timestamp                    amount     settlement
100aard    2021-03-13 01:21:36.007000         4000        No     <----Due to Rule 1
100aard    2021-03-13 01:23:36.007000         3000        No     <----Due to Rule 1
100aard    2021-03-13 01:33:36.007000         1000        Yes    
100aard    2021-03-13 01:21:36.007000        10300        No     <----Due to Rule 2
```

For Rule 1, I am using the following piece of code:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],errors = 'coerce')
gs = df.groupby(['id'])['timestamp'].diff().astype('timedelta64[s]').fillna(150)
df['Rule_No'] = np.where(gs >= f,'Yes','No')
```

The above code works fine except it doesn't mark the 1st transaction as 'No'. In fact it is giving the below results:

```
 id            timestamp                 amount   settlement
100aard    2021-03-13 01:21:36.007000     4000      Yes
100aard    2021-03-13 01:23:36.007000     3000      No
```

Rule 2 codes are working fine hence I am worried about the same.

What I am missing here?

Comment: The first and the last line of your dataframe have the same timestamp for the same transaction. Therefore, you last record should be 'No' due to Rule 1.

Comment: What If there are 3 or more consecutive transaction happens between 150 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I slightly modified your input data:

```
>>> df
        id               timestamp  amount
0  100aard 2021-03-13 01:17:36.007    2000  # Yes
1  100aard 2021-03-13 01:21:36.007    4000  # No, rule 1
2  100aard 2021-03-13 01:23:36.007    3000  # No, rule 1
3  100aard 2021-03-13 01:25:36.007    2000  # No, rule 1
4  100aard 2021-03-13 01:33:36.007    1000  # Yes
5  100aard 2021-03-13 01:37:36.007   10300  # No, rule 2
6  200aard 2021-03-12 05:24:12.007    1500  # Yes
```

Compute binary masks:

```
MINDELTA = pd.Timedelta(seconds=150)
MAXAMOUNT = 5000

r1a = df.groupby('id')['timestamp'].diff(1).lt(MINDELTA)
r1b = df.groupby('id')['timestamp'].diff(-1).abs().lt(MINDELTA)
r2 = df['amount'].ge(MAXAMOUNT)
```

For convenience way, I look for the timestamp differences "less than 150" rather than "greater than or equal to 150" because I want the records that not satisfied at least one rule (bitwise or). It's the same for amount.

```
df['settlement'] = 'Yes'
df.loc[r1a|r1b|r2, 'settlement'] = 'No'
```

```
>>> df
        id               timestamp  amount settlement
0  100aard 2021-03-13 01:17:36.007    2000        Yes
1  100aard 2021-03-13 01:21:36.007    4000         No
2  100aard 2021-03-13 01:23:36.007    3000         No
3  100aard 2021-03-13 01:25:36.007    2000         No
4  100aard 2021-03-13 01:33:36.007    1000        Yes
5  100aard 2021-03-13 01:37:36.007   10300         No
6  200aard 2021-03-12 05:24:12.007    1500        Yes
```

Comment: @AnuragDabas, I eventually fixed it ;-)

Comment: Ty! I modified my input data to take into account your comment about "3 or more consecutive transactions"

Comment: @Corralien: This doesn't solve the purpose. Based on your method, a single transaction by another `id` is getting marked as No.

Comment: @pythondumb. I fixed my answer. I hope this works for the other cases I don't know :)